# Data-64 image links on IE/Edge

Tags: internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I'm crafting an image with canvas and allowing the user to download it with a link. Browsers that support download will use that.

However, it doesn't work on IE nor Edge. Can't find any information relating this issue. I've made a quick jsbin for it.

https://jsbin.com/keyegazehu/edit?html,output

Basic code is something like this

```
<a href="data:image/png;base64," download="image.png">
  <img src="data:image/png;base64,">
</a>
```

It works on any other browser.

Comment: I tried it over Edge and I'm seeing an "Anonymous" link, clicking it made a menu appear with the ffg links as well (clone, save as template, export as gist) isn't that you were expecting?

Comment: forgot to mentioned that a big logo of the Edge image shows up too

Comment: I don't see that on Edge. When I click on the edge logo it should let me either download it or open a new tab with the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after much digging I couldn't find any suitable fix for this. However using https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/ is a good workaround as it deals with loads of quirks for all browsers.

If you run into this problem this is my suggestion.